# roc::rocblas not found when trying to install/build python-torchvision-rocm on Arch

Tags: archlinux, torchvision

I get an error when I run `yay -S python-torchvision-rocm` on Arch Linux. I have the `rocblas` package installed already.

```
AUR Explicit (1): python-torchvision-rocm-0.15.1-5
:: PKGBUILD up to date, skipping download: python-torchvision-rocm
1 python-torchvision-rocm                  (Build Files Exist)
==> Packages to cleanBuild?
==> [N]one [A]ll [Ab]ort [I]nstalled [No]tInstalled or (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> A
:: Deleting (1/1): /home/myusername/.cache/yay/python-torchvision-rocm
HEAD is now at 1553f68 remove additional FORCE_CUDA
warning: could not open directory 'pkg/': Permission denied
Removing pkg/
Removing src/
Removing vision-0.15.1.tar.gz
1 python-torchvision-rocm                  (Build Files Exist)
==> Diffs to show?
==> [N]one [A]ll [Ab]ort [I]nstalled [No]tInstalled or (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> N
==> Making package: python-torchvision-rocm 0.15.1-5 (Sat 08 Jul 2023 07:15:41 PM EDT)
==> Retrieving sources...
-> Downloading vision-0.15.1.tar.gz...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 12.4M    0 12.4M    0     0  10.1M      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 6202k
==> Validating source files with sha512sums...
vision-0.15.1.tar.gz ... Passed
:: (1/1) Parsing SRCINFO: python-torchvision-rocm
==> Making package: python-torchvision-rocm 0.15.1-5 (Sat 08 Jul 2023 07:15:44 PM EDT)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
-> Found vision-0.15.1.tar.gz
==> Validating source files with sha512sums...
vision-0.15.1.tar.gz ... Passed
==> Removing existing $srcdir/ directory...
==> Extracting sources...
-> Extracting vision-0.15.1.tar.gz with bsdtar
==> Starting prepare()...
==> Sources are ready.
==> Making package: python-torchvision-rocm 0.15.1-5 (Sat 08 Jul 2023 07:15:48 PM EDT)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> WARNING: Using existing $srcdir/ tree
==> Starting build()...
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.1.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.1.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Caffe2: Found gflags with new-style gflags target.
-- Caffe2: Found glog with new-style glog target.
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.13")
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Caffe2: Found protobuf with new-style protobuf targets.
-- Caffe2: Protobuf version 23.4.0
CMake Warning at /usr/lib/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:22 (message):
static library kineto_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND not found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/lib/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:127 (append_torchlib_if_found)
CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)


-- Found Torch: /usr/lib/libtorch.so
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/libpng.so (found version "1.6.40")
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/libjpeg.so (found version "80")
-- Configuring done (0.6s)
CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Targets.cmake:107 (set_target_properties):
The link interface of target "torch_hip_library" contains:

roc::rocblas

but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

* There is a typo in the target name.
* A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
* An ALIAS target is missing.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/lib/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:110 (include)
/usr/lib/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68 (find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)


-- Generating done (0.0s)
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
Aborting...
-> error making: python-torchvision-rocm-exit status 4
-> Failed to install the following packages. Manual intervention is required:
python-torchvision-rocm - exit status 4
```